# Can't boot into Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, boot-failure

When my computer loads the Grub menu shows up and gives the option to either boot to ubuntu or to Windows 7, however when I click on Windows 7 it writes some lines and then brings me back to the grub boot menu.

I tried repairing using boot-repair, and it didn't work, instead I now have 2 entries for Windows 7, and neither work.  Here is the URL:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1060937/

Please help!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you should report a "GRUB can't boot Windows" bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+filebug).
2. Then boot on a Windows CD ([32bits](http://freakshare.com/files/o2db6v0s/CyberNetNews.com_Windows_7_32-bit_Repair_Disc.iso.html) or [64bits](http://freakshare.com/files/56apzmkl/CyberNetNews.com_Windows_7_64-bit_Repair_Disc.iso.html)) then type `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` to repair direct access to Windows.
3. Finally use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to recover the GRUB menu.